# Can I set a dynamic database as a source for a dataset?

Tags: apache-superset

I have multiple databases which have the same exact schema (different data on each one, database per customer of a SaaS platform).

I would like to create a Dashboard (with charts, datasets) which could be populated by the permissions of the logged in user.

This means the dashboard will query the data from a specified source database, instead of a pre-defined one.

The premise is basically to de-couple a chart / dataset from a database and allow it to be parametrised.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case that is not really supported by Superset, but there's one workaround that I can think of that *might* work: you can define a `DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR` in your `superset_config.py` that routes to a different database depending on the user.

In your `superset_config.py`, add this function:

```py
def DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR(uri, params, username, security_manager, source):
    user = security_manager.find_user(username=username)
    if url.database = "db_name" and user and user.email.endswith("@examplea.com"):
        uri.host = "host-for-examplea.com"
    return uri, params
```

In the function above we're changing the host of the SQLAlchemy URL to `host-for-examplea.com` if the user has an email ending in `@examplea.com`.

To make it work, create a default database (which we called `db_name` in this example), and create all the charts/dashboards based on it. Then, users should be redirected to specific databases by the `DB_CONNECTION_MUTATOR`.

One serious problem that might happen is with caching, though. You should make sure that all caches are disabled to prevent users from seeing data from other databases.